# Using wp_editor() when not logged stopped working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I've build myself a custom page template. Within this template I'm using the `wp_editor()` function. Sadly, when I logout now from my wp site and go now to the page I want to see, I'm getting an error in my console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined
```

When I log back in, everything works quite fine. I've also tried to enqueue the editor script if a user isn't logged in this way:

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-tinymce' );
}
```

But this don't solved my issue. I've cleaned the cache every time and restarted the server.

So does anyone has an idea how I can get the `wp_editor()` function runnning with non-logged-in users?

**Update**

I've also tried:

```
wp_enqueue_editor()
```

With using the above function, I'm getting now another error. The first error is still there:

```
Failed to load plugin url: https://develop.pami.de/wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/de.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176222). It looks like your tinymce has not been initialized at first.

Comment: Tried out with no success.